# tinymce removes html

Tags: jquery, html, image, tinymce

I already searched this website (and google) but I cannot get this to work. I'm trying to insert an image in a tinymce textarea but the html necessary keeps getting removed when I click the "save" button (on tinymce UI).
I am using tinymce jquery version.

I already tried adding the following to tinymce.init:

```
cleanup: false,
verify_html : false,
media_strict: false,
valid_elements: "*[*]",
```

...but to no avail.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunalty, `valid_elements: "*[*]"`, is buggy.
You will need to set the tinymce configuration parmaters valid_elements and valid_children according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I just set it like this:
cleanup: false,
verify_html : false,
media_strict: false,
valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br",
extended_valid_elements : img[class=myclass|!src|border:0|alt|title|width|height]",

...and still nothing works. I can't even make some text bold. It just gets striped as soon as I click on save. :(

Comment: That script works with MCImageManager and MCFileManager, which have to be bought separately. Isn't there a free way to do this?

Comment: I just tried CKEditor and the exact same thing happens: ALL html tags are striped when I click submit on the form. Even something as simple as a bold tag. What could be wrong? There are no js errors of any kind.

Comment: it doesn't matter what kind of image src is inserted: see http://fiddle.tinymce.com/TLcaab/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could not get tinymce or ckeditor working, so I ended up using this one: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/
When I have some free time I'll try to understand what was going on. :P